# how to hide xhrs files in browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I am posting to a `php` file on my webpage using `jquery` and `ajax` quit frequently (once every 2 seconds).

After a few minutes when I open safari web inspector I see hundreds of `xhrs` files. Do they actually use space on the users computer?

Is there any way to hide them? Can other browsers, like `Chrome` and `IE` see them?

I am just sending simple data via `ajax`.

Comment: Your browser is simply logging HTTP traffic. You cannot hide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kapa mentioned, this is purely your browser logging the traffic.

Your question of "Do they actually use space on the computer" - This would be insignificant space (very little).

"Can you hide them" - You can change the URLs' your webpage is looking at / getting directed to, however, you cannot hide them, no (its a trace of what the webpage is telling the browser to do).

"Can any browser see this" - Each browser will log the traffic, so yes.

I hope that helped?